# How to make a MovieClip stick to the Flash player edge?

Tags: actionscript-3, stage

I have been starting to code in ActionScript, and tried to do this program. It draws a shape into the stage, and you can move it using the arrow keys. I added a "edge sticking" feature that sticks half of the shape to the edge. here's my code:

```
function freemove(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    switch (event.keyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.UP:
        {
            testing.y -= 5;
            if(testing.y < stage.width)
            {
                testing.y = 0;
                }
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.DOWN:
        {
            testing.y += 5;
            // FOR BOTTOM EDGE.
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.LEFT:
        {
            testing.x -= 5;
            if(testing.x < stage.height)
            {
                testing.x = 0;
                }
            break;
        }
        case Keyboard.RIGHT:
        {
            testing.x += 5;
            // FOR RIGHT EDGE.
            break;
        }
        }

    }
```

The problem is: It only works for the left and top edge. How can I make it work for the bottom and right edge? Thanks! =)

Comment: why are you testing y axis against width? That is the root of the problem.

Comment: It also confused me and someone I showed the code too. It also bugged me. In runtime, it works as expected with that config on. Seems I'm making weird code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// FOR BOTTOM EDGE.
if (shape.y + shape.height > stage.stageHeight)

// FOR RIGHT EDGE.
if (shape.x + shape.width > stage.stageWidth)
```

Also, you might confuse width and height in your LEFT and RIGHT handlers (why `y` is compared with width and `x` with height?)